# Changing camera background image proxy for easier viewing

Tags: tracking

In the camera settings under background images, there is a setting to change the video proxy to a smaller size to make it run faster. I'm using 4K footage and it's too slow to be useful. I tried changing it from full render to 25% but it makes the camera background image pink instead of just changing the resolution. Should I just create a low resolution image or is there something I'm forgetting to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Blender 2.83?
I would say you are luckier than me because when I change the proxy resolution I don't have any change at all in the 3D viewport :/
I am not sure if a manual reload of the clip is required - or a full project file reload maybe?

In any cases a pink image means the expected media is not found at the current time. This can be due to:

- The current time your scene is using is out of the media range (it can be after of before, even if there is a strange behavior for before in the way that after some time jog the first frame of the media is displayed instead of the pink fill). By moving the current time you should be able to reach the media range (which should not have changed btw).
- Or the proxy has not been generated, for some reason...

This is not really an answer but...
At this point I am wondering if this property is working correctly on this version...

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me.  Under xamera tap in background images, I went to color space and changed to desire selection and pink went away.